# I would Like to make this screen resolution good for all size of screen what i should change

Tags: android

I have few screen i my app and i try to make them good for all size of screen but no successful so i attach the screen and hope for help.

what i would like to get in this screen is:
    1.the widget43 to be on top of the screen 
    2.the widget49 in the middle of the screen
    3.the widget47 the problem one in the bottom of the screen even if the widget49 don't      take all the space.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/widget42"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/widget43"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="34px"
 android:background="@color/blue"
  >
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/convertedTitleTextView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="TextView"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   >
  </TextView>
  <Button
android:id="@+id/convertedBackButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="32px"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:onClick="backButtonOnClick"
android:text="Back" android:typeface="monospace" android:textColor="@color/white"         android:textColorHint="@color/blue" android:background="@color/blue">
 </Button>
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/convertedCancelButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="32px"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:onClick="cancelButtonOnClick"
 android:text="Cancel" android:background="@color/blue"    android:textColor="@color/white">
 </Button>
 </RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/widget49"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom"    android:layout_height="310dip">
 <ListView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:id="@+id/convertedListView" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/widget47" android:layout_above="@+id/widget49"  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/widget43" android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/widget47" android:background="@color/blue"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:id="@+id/countConvertedTextView" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what bad is going on with different screen size? better to put different size images in different drawable folders as i mentioned below.

drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi

Comment: The Relative_Layout(widget47) on different size screen is not always on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: first you have to change your main linearlayout to relativelayout. then you have to add android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" attribute in your widget27. now it will always come to bottom

Comment: i have done that an the result is Relative_Layout(widget47) is in taking all the space between the widget49 to the bottom. this mean yes is in the bottom but is change is size to a wrong one not like i went wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing...add this property in the relative layout which has id of widget47

```
android:layout_below="@+id/widget49"
```

So your relative layout will look like

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/widget47"
    android:layout_below="@+id/widget49" android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: One tip: If you really want to support multiple screen size and orientation coding in dp will give you less problems compared to px...

Comment: what was the problem? you wanted text view to stick below widget 49 didn't you? I have tried this code changed what I have shown you in snippet and it worked for me here....

Comment: What i wanted is to widget(47) to be in the bottom,i got the answer below,but thank you for you time!!!